# Word for a problem that goes away when a larger thing changes?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, phrasal-verbs

What is a word or expression for a problem has effectively gone away because of a larger change that makes the problem no longer a problem?

I'm thinking "obviated" or "made unnecessary," but it sounds awkward to me.

For example: The problem of the dripping faucet I meant to fix was "obviated" by doing a gut renovation (with all new plumbing) of the whole bathroom.

Or: My need to find a ride to the airport was "obviated" by my getting sick and cancelling the whole trip.

Or: I'm not fixing a typo in a certain draft of a document, as it was made unnecessary by having wrote a new draft of the document from scratch.

Comment: Obviated *is* the right word, however awkward it may sound. It is high on @JohnLawler's "falutin" scale, however, so it would sound funny if you're talking to the waitress at Denny's. But if you're merely eating at Denny's and talking to people who know what it means, you don't need to feel self-conscious.

Comment: There are obvious choices that are more common words, including *removed* and *made unnecessary*, the latter of which you mentioned. It is not clear just what you are asking for.

Comment: Something doesn't obviate a problem or a need. Something obviates an action, by eliminating the need for it. So in the third example, "obviated" the fixing of the typo.  But in the first two examples the problem or need was  "eliminated by" (or "subsumed by" or "made irrelevant by") the bigger problem or action.

Comment: In my opinion, obsolete is a better word that is less archaic and more understood.

Comment: A relatively common phrase for this situation these days is to declare the earlier problem **rendered moot**, which includes both solutions which subsume the original and those which cause the original solution to no longer apply for some other reason, as in: "My need to find a ride to the airport was rendered moot by my getting sick and cancelling the whole trip."  Hmmm. It has just occurred to me that I should enter this as an answer.  I'll do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [relatively](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rendered%20moot&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crendered%20moot%3B%2Cc0) [common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=render%20it%20moot&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crender%20it%20moot%3B%2Cc0) if still somewhat colorful phrase for this situation these days is to declare the earlier problem or proposed solution **rendered moot**, which includes both solutions which subsume the original and those which cause the original action to no longer apply for some other reason, as in:

> My need to find a ride to the airport was **rendered moot** by my getting sick and cancelling the whole trip.

or

> The problem of the dripping faucet I meant to fix was **rendered moot** by doing a gut renovation (with all new plumbing) of the whole bathroom.

Large portions of the American public will incorrectly believe the second word of this phrase is "mute" instead of "moot", but they will easily understand the phrase regardless.

Comment: Interesting usage note [here](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=moot).

Comment: That's fascinating, @Amphiteóth (pronunciation?), I hadn't realized the definitions were essentially opposites. Good response, Mark. It took me 3 upvotes just to get my answer above water!

Comment: @Amphiteóth - I'm embarrassed to say, I've used the term in my legal writing to indicate an issue was essentially beyond debate and was quite surprised to see the other articulation, but there it is in *Black's Law*, first interpretation, though listed as *archaic*, which isn't a problem for me as I tend to cleave to tradition.

Comment: @LittleEva In the end it may be _rendered_ or _made_ plays a significant part here. Not clear why s.o. didn't just contribute _made irrelevant_. Anyways, cheers!

Comment: @LittleEva, I'm embarrassed myself to note that I wasn't really aware of the other meaning for moot despite having heard it in legal dramas and the like.  I had always assumed the characters were saying an issue was irrelevant or no longer applicable when they were likely saying it was settled.  Ah well, one only knows what one knows!

Comment: +1 Mark. I'll be employing the term, in its newly discovered articulation, on as many occasions as possible (and those possibilities have just increased, exponentially) for the foreseeable future. Friends & family will be hating on me, but at least I won't be fooled again.

Comment: Oh, Mark, I previously dwelt in Sv, CA, *pre*-revolution era, lovely weather. 17 to Santa Cruz on my cousin’s Kawasaki 1000. Great days!

Comment: Alas, I was not here pre-revolution.  I grew up in the Midwest and only came west in 1991.  That was pre-Google, but not pre-tech, as I came out specifically for technology. 17 to Santa Cruz is, alas, now impassable due to traffic on weekends unless you set out before 7 am.  :-)

Comment: "Rendered moot" is a nice enough expression, but does it really fit? Methinks not: [moot means debatable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moot). In none of the three scenarios given is there any room whatsoever for debate: there is certainly now no need for a ride to the airport, or to fix the drip or the typo.

Comment: It [also means](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=moot) "irrelevant", which is the meaning I was going for, and in the phrase *rendered moot* it essentially always means that (as something would rarely if ever be said to have been "rendered" debatable).

Answer (score 3):

> **Subsume** *verb*:
>
> [with object] Include or absorb (something) in something else:
>
> **1.Subsume is to absorb, contain or include something into something else.**
>
> See, Oxford Dictionary, “subsume” [**Link**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/subsume)

• The task of fixing the dripping faucet was "subsumed" in the renovation of the whole bathroom.

• The problem of fixing all the typos in the original document was subsumed by writing a whole new document.

> See, Your Dictionary [**Link**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/subsume)

Answer (score 2):

**Supersede** - to take the place of (someone or something that is old, no longer useful, etc.) : to replace (someone or something) ([merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supersede))

Answer (score 0):

**Obsolete**

The problem was made obsolete with the new technology.